# How can I use stringstream to keep a quotation mark in a string?

Tags: c++, string, formatting

I have a vector of strings that contain numbers, words, spaces, and even weird characters like quotation marks. I am trying to read it all in using a stringstream so I can separate the doubles from strings.

When I do this:

stringstream contains

> 4165 This package contains 12 1/2" Screws

Code:

```
stringstream >> mydouble 
stringstream >> mystring
```

mydouble contains

```
4165
```

Then the only thing that gets read into mystring is

> This package contains 12 1/2

How can I let it keep the entire line?

Sometimes my file contains this:

> 4165 This package contains 2 1/2" Screws
>
> 65 This package contains 12> 1/2" Screws
>
> This package contains 1 screw

Comment: What is mystring's type? The way you have it, if that's a `std::string` or a char array, the only thing in there should be "This".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regrettably, the stream extraction operator `>>` is not good at the kind of thing you wish it to do.  The right way to do what you want is to fetch the whole line by

```
std::getline(stringstream, myline);
```

then to write code to parse the line.

How to parse the line?  Five options come to mind:

1. Write your own code to do it without relying on special tools.
2. Use Lex/Flex and Yacc/Bison.
3. Use Boost Spirit.
4. Use POSIX `<regex.h>`.
5. Use C++11 `<regex>` or TR1 `<tr1/regex>`.

None of these however is entirely trivial.  If you want to know, for your application, I'd probably go with choice 1, choice 3 or choice 5.  Whatever you choose to do, good luck to you.

If you don't know where to start, why don't you look up `std::getline()`, presented in `<string>`, and `std::atoi()`, presented in `<cstdlib>`?  These should afford you some ideas as to where to go next.

Comment: Correction:  An earlier version of the answer referred to `std::getline()` as presented in `<iostream>`.  That was the wrong header.  There are two, distinct `std::getline()` functions in the standard library, and you want the other one, the one presented in `<string>`.  I have corrected the answer above accordingly.